# Google Assistant comes up blank. How do I fix it?

Tags: google-assistant

I have Galaxy A32 5G and the Android version is 11. When I ask Google something, it comes up blank and says "here are some details."

> [image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, could you [edit] and mention the device model, Android version, and upload the screenshot of the issue?